# Passing events from Child to Parent Component-Angular

Tags: angular, components, interaction, eventemitter

I am new to Angular and here is my issue:

I have a child component where I am handling the cell click event of a grid, and in the callback I have an EventEmitter and is declared like `@Output() cellClicked :any;`.
I am instantiating the EventEmitter inside the callback function, like in the example code below:

```
        onCellClicked($event){
            this.cellClicked = new EventEmitter();
            this.cellClicked.emit($event);  
        }
```

In the parent component template I have placed this grid

```
    <data-grid 
        [gridData]="restrictionsAll.restrictions" 
        [columnDefinitionsPath]="restrictionsAll.agGridConfigPath" 
        (getApi)="getGridApi($event)" 
         >
    </data-grid>
```

and in the component.ts for parent I am trying to capture the 
emitted event.

```
    cellClicked($event)
         {
            console.log('onCellClicked: ' + $event.rowIndex + ' ' + $event.colDef.field);
      }
```

When I debug the code control is reaching the break point in the child component but it's not passing to parent component in the `cellClicked` method. Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not implementing the event anywhere

In your container parent component

```
<data-grid 
    (cellClicked)="cellClickedInParent($event)"
    [gridData]="restrictionsAll.restrictions" 
    [columnDefinitionsPath]="restrictionsAll.agGridConfigPath" 
    (getApi)="getGridApi($event)" 
     >
</data-grid>
```

In the parent component handle the event

```
cellClickedInParent(event){
   console.log(event) //////// this works
}
```